# Why do I get linker errors during build of C++ AMP project

Tags: c++, c++-amp

I try to make a system, where I need a activator function. This activator function may have a state, so I tried to put the state into an concurrency::array_view. When I try to build the solution, I get the following linker error.

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static double __thiscall ArtNeuroNet::ActivationFunctions::Activator::function(double,class Concurrency::array_view) restrict(cpu, amp)" (?function@Activator@ActivationFunctions@ArtNeuroNet@@SENNV?$array_view@N$00@Concurrency@@@*DZ*_B) referenced in function _wmain  D:\Projekte\ArtNeuroNet\ArtNeuroNet\ArtNeuroNet.obj ArtNeuroNet

Error   3   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   D:\Projekte\ArtNeuroNet\Debug\ArtNeuroNet.exe   1   1   ArtNeuroNet

My simplified activator looks like

```
double Activator::lin_function(double x, concurrency::array_view<double, 1> state)
    restrict(cpu, amp)
{
    if (x > state[StateParameterType::ThresholdParameter])
        return 1;
    else if (x < -(state[StateParameterType::ThresholdParameter]))
        return 0;
    else
        return state[StateParameterType::AlphaParameter] * x + 0.5f;
}

double* Activator::getInitialState(double alpha)
{
    double stateCpu[] = {1.0, 0.5};

    if (alpha != NULL)
        stateCpu[0] = alpha;

    return stateCpu;
}
```

My activator creation looks like

```
Activator activator = *(new Activator());
double* stateCpu = activator.getInitialState(1.0);

concurrency::array_view<double, 1> state(2, stateCpu);

activator.lin_function(0.4, state);
```

For testing purpose, I added the last line, which is the call **activator.lin_function(0.4, state)**. If I comment that line out, the project gets build without any problems.

My question is now, what am I missing out or am I doing, which I'm acctually not supposed to do?

**EDIT**

The method lin_function is private. However, in the Activator there's a public method function which calls the private method lin_function. For simplification-reasons, I left that part of the source coude out. Both methods are accessable, as I otherwise wouldn't be able to build the solution, when the call to the method lin_function is commented out.

Activator resides completely within the same project, which is a console-application for now.

The lin_function relies on a single state variable. However, a threshold-implementation of the activator function doesn't need any state storage at all. Changing everything to the threshold-activation function and commenting the rest out reacts the same way. In particular that is „lin_function commented out -> no linker error, otherwise –> linker error“

**EDIT 2**

For the Activator there exists a header (Activator.h) and source-file (Activator.cpp). It somehow seems that the linker can't find any method from the header which is declared as **restrict(cpu, amp)**.

```
// Doesn't get found and throws linker error
double Activator::function(double x)
    restrict(cpu, amp)
{
    return (x >= 0) ? 1 : 0;
}

// Get's found and no linker errors occur
double Activator::function(double x)
{
    return (x >= 0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

**EDIT 3**

After defining all methods containing a restrict(amp, cpu) as static in the header-file, everything did build correctly and ran without problems.

**Is there actually a restriction on methods needed to be static when restrict(amp, cpu) is used?**

Comment: I can't answer your question, but in `Activator::getInitialState` you're returning a pointer to a local. Not a good idea.

Comment: @Henrik: Good point. I changed it to create a std::vector<double> outside and am now handing over a reference of the vector to getInitialState-method, where then its values get filled. However, this doesn't change anything concerning the linker error.

Comment: I don't think this is a C++ AMP related error. And I'd need more information to track it down. Things that come to mind are; is the lin_function public? Is Activator imported from another project with different calling convention etc? What happens if you remove the array_view parameter from lin_function does this work?

Comment: OK. So this is totally an AMP thing. I've no idea why this got a down vote. It's a completely reasonable question. Which version of VS are you using 2012 or 13? This will effect the errors you see. See my full answer below.

Comment: My development environment is Visual Studio 2013, Windows 8.1 64 Bit and a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 770.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the limitations on C++  AMP with respect to classes and functions etc. You are also limited to a subset of supported C++ types but I don't think that is the issue here.

> References and pointers (to a compatible type) may be used locally but
>   cannot be captured by  a lambda. Function pointers,
>   pointer-to-pointer, and the like are not allowed; neither are static
>   or global variables.
>
> Classes must meet more rules if you wish to use instances of them.
>   They must have no virtual functions or virtual inheritance.
>   Constructors, destructors, and other nonvirtual functions are allowed.
>   The member variables must all be of compatible types, which could of
>   course include instances of other classes as long as those classes
>   meet the same rules. The actual code in your amp-compatible function
>   is not running on a CPU and therefore can’t do certain things that you
>   might be used to doing:
>
> - recursion
> - pointer casting
> - use of virtual functions
> - new or delete
> - RTTI or dynamic casting
> - goto
> - throw, try, or catch
> - access to globals or statics
> - inline assembler

This is taken from my book and I apologize because it is misleading. What isn't made clear is that this applies to classes that you wish to pass to AMP kernels as data. Not to classes that have `restrict(amp)` methods on them. This is only supported for static methods because it is not possible to share the class `this` pointer with the GPU as it refers to an object instance on the CPU.

So the following is an example of a class that meets the above requirements and can be passed to an AMP kernel:

```
class stuff
{
public:
    int a;

    stuff(int v) : a(v) { }
};
```

`stuff` also meets the requirements for supported types as `int` is supported by AMP.

The following class uses `stuff` in an `array_view`:

```
class test_case
{
public:
    test_case()
    {
    }

    static int amp_method(int a) restrict(amp, cpu)
    {
        return a * a;
    };

    void test_amp()
    {
        concurrency::array_view<stuff, 1> data(100);
        concurrency::parallel_for_each(data.extent, 
            [data](concurrency::index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
        {
            data[idx].a = amp_method(data[idx].a);
        });
        data.synchronize();
    };

    void test_cpu()
    {
        std::vector<int> data(100, 0);
        for (auto& d : data)
        {
            d = amp_method(d);
        }
    }
};
```

If you remove the `static` modifier on `amp_method` then you get the following error on VS 2013.

> warning C4573: the usage of 'test_tools_tests::test_case::amp_method'
>   requires the compiler to capture `this` but the current default
>   capture mode does not allow it

You may see something different in 2012. One of the weaknesses of the first AMP release was it's errors. This has improved in 2013.

On reflection this all seems really reasonable. How could I pass `this` to the GPU when it refers to code running on the CPU?

Note that `restrict` cannot be applied to classes.

Thanks for highlighting this issue. I guess I should update the book errata.

Comment: Thanks for your help on clarifying me on the restrictions of C++ AMP. Definitely needed, as I'm currently doing my Master Thesis on building an artificial neuronal network in C++ AMP.